How to set --grpc-web by default for argocd invocations
In order to suppress the following warning when executing argocd commands:
WARN[0000] Failed to invoke grpc call. Use flag --grpc-web in grpc calls. To avoid this warning message, use flag --grpc-web.

I am told to set the --grpc-web flag. That's nice, but I'm tired of adding it to every single command.
Is there a way to configre the CLI to use that flag by default? Something like .argocdrc? I searched the docs but couldn't find anything. Did I miss something?

If you pass --grpc-web to argocd login it saves it to your ~/.argocd/config (or ~/.config/argocd/config, depending on your system).
argocd login argocd-server-argocd.apps.example.com --grpc-web


Nit: The config actually lives in ~/.config/argocd/config.

seems to be system-dependent, on my system (WSL) it's really ~/.argocd/config.
